# If error then insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to insert data into a table based on XACT_STATE. For example:

```
IF(XACT_STATE() = 1)
        BEGIN
           INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ()
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END
    ELSE
    IF(XACT_STATE() = -1)
        BEGIN
           INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES ()
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END

    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ERRORNUMBER,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ERRORSEVERITY,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ERRORSTATE,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ERRORPROCEDURE,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ERRORLINE,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERRORMESSAGE1
```

If this is not possible, is there an alternative?

Comment: @NathanOliver, the user was not yelling. All Caps is valid SQL syntax.

Comment: If the transaction is classified as uncommitable, then you can't execute a write operation like the INSERT INTO TABLE2 in your example, you can only do read operations and rollback.

Comment: @In the title, that's **very** arguable. Because he *could* have used lowercase. Actually, the in-your-face-effect of all-caps has much stronger weight, as the alternative is also right.

Comment: To clarify, I used all caps because that is the syntax to use when using reserved words for SQL. At least that's what I learned.

Comment: Well, I wasn't accusing you of being obnoxious, just making you aware that you can do it differently, and that will likely be better received, at least for the title. And while it isn't my preference for code in the body, that's simply personal preference, should just be consistent (and it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do what you are trying to do (insert into an alternative table if first insert fails) .But I would do it using TRY..CATCH blocks ,,,, something like.......

```
BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
           INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ()
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
     BEGIN
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
     END

           INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES ()
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    SELECT  ERROR_NUMBER()    AS ERRORNUMBER,
            ERROR_SEVERITY()  AS ERRORSEVERITY,
            ERROR_STATE()     AS ERRORSTATE,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ERRORPROCEDURE,
            ERROR_LINE()      AS ERRORLINE,
            ERROR_MESSAGE()   AS ERRORMESSAGE1

END CATCH
```

Comment: The only thing I had to do was move the ROLLBACK TRANSACTION to before the INSERT INTO table2 VALUES